# Отступы между компонентами внутри LinearLayout

Tags: android

Внутри LinearLayout расположены две кнопки

```
<LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/btn_show" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Мне надо чтобы кнопка floatingactionbutton была расположена с отступом 8dp от правого края. Но она как прилипла к первой кнопки и что я не задаю paddingLeft или marginLeft они все равно располагаются вместе.
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: используйте FrameLayout в корне, а FloatingActionButton уберите из LL в корень.

Comment: что значит добавить FloatingActionButton в корень? Мне надо, что бы эти две кнопки были расположены в одной плоскости

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `marginStart` вместо `marginLeft`. Возьмите за привычку писать start/end вместо left/right, такой подход учитывает языки с направлением письма справа налево ([RTL](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2#RTL)).